# how to get Ip add of ssh user who is currently running a specific process?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, terminal, process

An ssh server has a process that is started by a user who is logged in through ssh. I need to find a way to get the IP address of this user who executed a specific program "chrome for example" through shell.

I tried this command:

```
ps -aux | grep "chrome username"
```

Now how can I get the IP address of the machine that the user is using? you.is there a way through shell ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Now how can I get the IP address of the machine that the user is
>   using?

Well, use for example `w` (my emphasis):

```
NAME
       w - Show who is logged on and what they are doing.

SYNOPSIS
       w [options] user [...]

DESCRIPTION
       w  displays  information  about the users currently on the machine, and
       their processes.  The header shows, in this order,  the  current  time,
       how  long  the  system  has  been running, how many users are currently
       logged on, and the system load averages for the past 1, 5, and 15  min‐
       utes.

       The  following entries are displayed for each user: login name, the tty
       name, the remote host, login time, idle time, JCPU, PCPU, and the  com‐
       mand line of their current process.
```

Also try [this](https://is.gd/5UXSNB) if you want more examples.

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind, you beat me to it :-).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `netstat` or `ss` for finding the remote address of an SSH connection but you must be root in order to see this information for other users.